# How to find centroid of this region bounded by surfaces

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am having difficulty find the centroid of the region that is bound by the surfaces $x^2+y^2+z^2-2az=0$ and $3x^2+3y^2-z^2=0$ (lying above $xy$ plane, consider the inner region). I know the first surface is a sphere, while the second is an infinite cone.

I just dont know how to even approach it as I dont know how to even visualize these surfaces.

Can anyone help?

My only thoughts would be to probably use spherical coordinates.

My possible thoughts( I have no clue if this will work, just some thoughts)

if we had

$$\rho^{2}=x^2+y^2+z^2$$

$$x=\rho\sin(\psi)\cos(\theta)$$

$$y=\rho\sin(\psi)\sin(\theta)$$

$$z=\rho\sin(\psi)$$

We could do some rearranging

$\rho=2acos(\psi)$

Since we are only considering above xy plane, maybe then $\theta$ would only run though fourth quadrant?

In regard to the centroid aspect, I know my answer will need to be of the form $C=(X_{c},Y_{c},Z_{c})$ where each component is obtained by evaluating the respective integral and dividing by the total mass.

But I am not sure, so looking for help.

Update: A suggestion was made to use cylindrical coordinates instead.

If I were to try this, I would have

$$x=r\cos\theta$$

$$y=r\sin\theta$$

$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$

$$z=z$$

And from rearranging I would have

$r^2+(z-a)^2=a^2$
and
$3r^2=z^2$

$$r=\pm \sqrt{\frac{z^2}{3}}$$

But I am still left confused on how to tie it all together. I am still wondering this even after all this time. I really would like some advice and help. Anyone? I am tried all I know and tried the current answer, but I am making no progress.

Comment: I believe you want $r=\rho\sin\psi$ instead of $z=\rho\sin\psi$.

Comment: Actually, "the inner region" is meaningless. You must specify what side of the surfaces must be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By symmetry, you have that $\overline{x}=\overline{y}=0$; so you just need to find $\overline{z}$.

If you use spherical coordinates, you have

$\hspace{.5 in}\displaystyle\overline{z}=\frac{\int z\;dV}{\int 1 \;dV}$ where

$\;\;\displaystyle\int z\;dV=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\int_0^{2a\cos\psi}(\rho\cos\psi)(\rho^2\sin\psi)\;d\rho d\psi d\theta$ and

$\;\;\displaystyle\int 1\;dV=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\int_0^{2a\cos\psi}(\rho^2\sin\psi)\;d\rho d\psi d\theta$.

---

explanation:

A ray through the solid emanating from the origin exits along the surface of the sphere, which is given by $\rho=2a\cos\psi$.

The maximum value of $\psi$ is on the cone,  where $\psi=\frac{\pi}{6}$ since $\displaystyle\tan\psi=\frac{r}{z}=\frac{\frac{z}{\sqrt{3}}}{z}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Thanks but I am still not sure about the last part, ie how to find $\alpha$

Comment: @Quality I have updated my answer.

Comment: Can you tell me if you get 3a/8 for the z, or 37a/28?

Answer (score 0):

For the first equation, complete the square in $z$... that is, convert the equation to the form $x^2 + y^2 + (z - q)^2 = r^2$.  That will give you a sphere centered at $\{0,0,q\}$ of radius $r$.  You must express $q$ and $r$ in terms of your $a$.

For the second equation, note that the region is rotationally symmetric about the $z$ axis because the $x$-$y$ dependence is of the form $\alpha (x^2 + y^2)$ or $\alpha r^2$.  That radius $r$ depends upon $z$.  Hence this region is cone shaped.

To visualize, why not just use some simple computer plotting routine?

Note that both regions are symmetric around the $z$ axis, and thus the centroid must have coordinates $\{ 0, 0, z_0 \}$ for some $z_0$.  Just perform the integral to find the center of mass in the $z$ direction.

Exploit the *cylindrical* symmetry of the problem, not the *spherical* (non) symmetry:  Express everything in terms of $r$ (distance from vertical axis) and $z$.  Only the $z$ integral is non-trivial.

Comment: Is your q the same as what I had for a? And when I complete the square I get $x^2+y^2+(z-a)^2=a^2$

Comment: , I tried to update my answer but I am still confused. If possible could you go into more details? That would be very much appreciated

Comment: Hello?? I am still wondering this and have questions about your post. You say express in terms of a, is this what I did in my first comment?

Answer (score 0):

We can solve for $a=1$ and in the end multiply by $a$.

As said, in cylindrical coordinates

$$r^2+(z-1)^2\le 1,\\
3r^2\le z^2.$$

The intersection of the two surfaces is a circle in the plane $z=\frac32$ (by eliminating $r^2$).

We can decompose the domain in horizontal slices, which are disks of section $\pi r^2$, and split for the cone and the sphere. Then

$$\bar z=a\frac{\int_0^{3/2}z\frac{z^2}3dz+\int_{3/2}^2z(2z-z^2)dz}{\int_0^{3/2}\frac{z^2}3dz+\int_{3/2}^2(2z-z^2)dz}.$$

The integrands are polynomials, so the computation is straightforward.